# Convert all images to PNG on file upload

Tags: php, functions, images, uploads

On my site I have a front end form for users to upload multiple images, using the following code ---

```
if (!empty($_FILES['vidPix']['tmp_name'][0])) {
                    $i = 1;
                    $files = $_FILES['vidPix'];
                    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                            $file = array(
                                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                            );
                            $_FILES = array("sight" . $i => $file);
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

                        $mfile =  wp_handle_upload($files, $upload_overrides );                          
                            $newvidPix = sight("sight" . $i, $v_Id);
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
remove_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

                            if ($i == 1) {
                                update_post_meta($v_Id, '_thumbnail_id', $newvidPix);
                            }
                                add_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', $newvidPix, false);
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
```

This works fine but now I want to make it so that the files are converted to PNG, then saved to the folder and getting rid of the old file. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550015/convert-jpg-gif-image-to-png-in-php) that suggests the following code -

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file)), "output.png");
```

Im not sure how to get it work with my upload though. How would I go about this?

**UPDATE - FOR SINGLE FILE UPLOAD**

```
if(isset($_POST["ebc_submit"])) {

    $uploadedfile2 = $_FILES ['ebc_upload'];
    if (! empty ( $uploadedfile2 ['name'] )) {
        $upload_overrides = array (
            'test_form' => false 
        );

add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

                        $endpic = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile2, $upload_overrides );

remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
remove_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

    $im = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $endpic['file'] ) );
    if ( false !== $im ) {
        $filename = pathinfo( $endpic['file'], PATHINFO_FILENAME );
        $to = dirname( $endpic['file'] ) . '/' . $filename . '.png';

        // Creates the image and saves it in `$to`.
        imagepng( $im, $to );

        // Frees the image from memory.
        imagedestroy( $im );

        // Deletes the original file.
        unlink( $endpic['file'] );

}
// Convert the image to PNG and delete the old image.
attachment_to_png( $uploadedfile2 );

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated answer)*

The `sight()` function not only uploads the image, but also creates an attachment (i.e. a post of the `attachment` type); hence, I updated the code — it's now in a `function` named `attachment_to_png`, and that it uses the `get_attached_file()` to get the image file attached to that attachment, and the `update_attached_file()` to update the file path.

So please follow these steps:

1. Add this to the theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```
   function attachment_to_png( $att_id ) {
       $file = get_attached_file( $att_id );
       if ( ! $file ) {
           return false;
       }

       // Check MIME and make sure it's not already a PNG image.
       $mime = strtolower( mime_content_type( $file ) );
       if ( ! preg_match( '#^image/([a-z]{3,})$#', $mime, $m ) ||
           'png' === $m[1]
       ) {
           return false;
       }

       $im = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file ) );
       if ( false !== $im ) {
           $filename = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
           $to = dirname( $file ) . '/' . $filename . '.png';

           // Creates the image and saves it in `$to`.
           imagepng( $im, $to );

           // Frees the image from memory.
           imagedestroy( $im );

           // Deletes the original file.
           unlink( $file );

           // Update the attached file.
           update_attached_file( $att_id, $to );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add this after the `remove_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');`:

   ```
   // Convert the image to PNG and delete the old image.
   attachment_to_png( $newvidPix );
   ```

**Additional Note**

I don't think this is needed.. so you should just remove it...

```
$mfile =  wp_handle_upload($files, $upload_overrides );
```

---

### UPDATED Dec 03 2018 UTC

*(Updated for the single file upload)*

1. You shouldn't use the `$im` stuff and simply use the `attachment_to_png()` function. And call the function like so: `attachment_to_png( 123 )` where `123` is the attachment ID.
2. Use `media_handle_upload()` which creates an attachment post for the uploaded image, and not `wp_handle_upload()`.

So try this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST["ebc_submit"] ) ) {
    $uploadedfile2 = $_FILES['ebc_upload'];
    if ( ! empty( $uploadedfile2['name'] ) ) {
        $upload_overrides = array(
            'test_form' => false
        );

        add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
        add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing' );

        // Load media_handle_upload() and other media/image/file functions.
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';

        // $v_Id is the ID of the post where the image should be attached to.
        $endpic = media_handle_upload( 'ebc_upload', $v_Id, array(), $upload_overrides );

        remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
        remove_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing' );

        // Convert the image to PNG and delete the old image.
        if ( $endpic && ! is_wp_error( $endpic ) ) {
            attachment_to_png( $endpic );
            //echo 'Success!';
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATED Dec 05 2018 UTC

If you're 100% sure about *not* going to be using unique file names; i.e. when you upload an image with the same name as a previously uploaded image, then you can create a callback function which will be used by `wp_unique_filename()`, where you return the original (but sanitized) file name, like so:

```
// Add this to the theme's functions.php
function no_unique_filename( $dir, $name, $ext ) {
    return $name;
}
```

And then, in the `$upload_overrides` (see previous update), add `unique_filename_callback` like so:

```
$upload_overrides = array(
    'test_form'                => false,
    'unique_filename_callback' => 'no_unique_filename',
);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I've tried both suggestions and it still gives me a jpg file.

Comment: Actually, this part — `wp_handle_upload($files, $upload_overrides );` — it should be `$file` and not `$files`. But I guess that's just a typo in the question? And can I see the code for the `sight()` function?

Comment: the $files part isnt a typo.. and the sights code is -- `if(!function_exists('sight')) {
function sight($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
 // check to make sure its a successful upload
 if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
 require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
 $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
 return $attach_id;
}
}`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I saw why my previous code didn't work for you, but I've updated it, so please check the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @rich I saw (in my email) *parts* of your previous comments (that you've deleted..), so if you want, I could update the function so that it also accepts a file *path* as a parameter. Thanks for accepting the answer. :)

Comment: hi i am trying to use your code to work with another upload function, which is similar to the one in my original question, except it is for single file upload. Unfortunately Im unable to get it work. I have added the code to my question. @sallycj

Comment: Hi Rich. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: works perfect except instead of rewriting files with the same name, it is renaming them. How can I change this?

Comment: What do you mean "renaming them"? I tried and didn't get that issue, except when the original name contains *special* characters such as `(` and `)`. But in that case, the renaming is a default behavior.

Comment: i meant, if i have a file such as "picture-1.png" , when image with same name is uploaded, the new file is named "picture-1-1.png"

Comment: In that case, check the updated answer. :)

Comment: ok thanks ill try it out. Right now trying to change from png to jpeg (to reduce file size) using imagejpeg, but for some reason its not creating the image.

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question on Stack Overflow..

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to get things figured out myself. I do have another question though that maybe you can help me with -- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319113/limit-amount-of-photos-uploaded-per-cpt-post

Comment: I've just posted an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319113/limit-amount-of-photos-uploaded-per-cpt-post/321867#321867) there. Check it out and let me know.