# limit amount of photos uploaded per cpt post

Tags: custom-field, uploads, forms, images

On my site I have a front end form for users to create a post and upload images. It works fine however I cant seem to figure out how to limit the number of images per post.

The image attachments get saved to a custom field, so is there a way to limit the amount of values allowed to the custom field?

I also came across [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-can-you-limit-the-number-of-images-videos-that-can-be-uploaded-to-a-wordpr) but was unable to get it to work.

current code in use for uploading files --

```
// THE PHOTO UPLOAD HERE
if(isset($_POST["savepics2"])) {

$attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $v_Id ) );
$count = count( $attachments );
if ($count == 25) {
echo 'limit reached';
} else {


if (!empty($_FILES['vidPix']['tmp_name'][0])) {
                    $i = 1;
                    $files = $_FILES['vidPix'];
                    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                            $file = array(
                                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                            );
                            $_FILES = array("sight" . $i => $file);
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');

                        $mfile =  wp_handle_upload($files, $upload_overrides );             

                            $newvidPix = sight("sight" . $i, $v_Id);
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
remove_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'no_image_resizing');
// Convert the image to PNG and delete the old image.
attachment_to_png( $newvidPix );

                            if ($i == 1) {
                                update_post_meta($v_Id, '_thumbnail_id', $newvidPix);
                            }
                                add_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', $newvidPix, false);
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code written so far?

Comment: sorry about the delay. I've updated the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so — refer to the `// {comment}`:

```
if (isset($_POST["savepics2"])) {
    // Set max number of files allowed.
    $max_files = 25;

    $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $v_Id ) );
    $count = count( $attachments );

    // Check if limit already reached.
    if ($count >= $max_files) {
        echo 'limit reached';
    // If not, then upload the files.
    } else {
        if (!empty($_FILES['vidPix']['tmp_name'][0])) {
            $i = 1;
            $files = $_FILES['vidPix'];

            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                // Check if limit already reached.
                if ( $count >= $max_files ) {
                    echo 'limit reached';
                    break;
                }

                // If not, then upload next file.
                if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                    ...your code here...
                }

                $i++;
                $count++; // increment the count
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i havent tested yet but question, since the input accepts multiple files, if a scenario where lets say - user has already upload 15 photos. He tries selecting 15 more photos to upload, what happens then ?

Comment: Assuming the max files is 20, then only 5 of the extra 15 photos would be uploaded - the browser does upload all, but won't actually be uploaded to WordPress (or the target destination). For front-end solution, you can use JavaScript to remove the extra photos - I can help, if you can show the form HTML.

Comment: Ok thanks Im going to test it out. As far as the form, its a lot of code, I have a lot going on with it, is there something specific I can show you that may help?

Comment: Try this [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVWvPZ/left/).